# How to return the full Object inserted in mongo using post API using ReactiveMongo

Tags: scala, reactivemongo

I am studying Scala programming to create RestAPI service for my project, using Play framework and ReactiveMongoDB.

I am trying to insert an object to db, and as a response from insert I want to retrieve the object created with the Options Data that I generate on Repository ( ex: the Id is generated directly from Mongo).

The photo below shows the model I use. The marker_id, _creationDate and the _updateDate are set on the repository.

```
case class Point_LocationModel(
id: Option[BSONObjectID],
marker_id: Option[String],
step: String,
backgroundTargetName: String,
firstPoint: Option[PointModel],
secondPoint: Option[PointModel],
x: String,
y: String,
z: String,
rotation: String,
note: String,
tag: String,
work_session_id: String,
_creationDate: Option[DateTime],
_updateDate: Option[DateTime] )
```

This is the repository that I use to return a map of response data but I see that the marker_id , id, _creationDate, _updateDate  are not set on the response data (line 53).

```
def create(point: Point_LocationModel)(implicit
      writer: BSONDocumentWriter[Point_LocationModel]
  ) = {
    logger.info(s"output pointInserted point:  ${point}")
    val pointInserted = collection.flatMap(
      _.insert(ordered = false)
        .one(
          point.copy(
            marker_id = Some(BSONObjectID.generate().stringify),
            _creationDate = Some(new DateTime()),
            _updateDate = Some(new DateTime())
          )
        )
        .map((_, point))
    )
    val test1 = Await.result(pointInserted, Duration.Inf)
    logger.info(s"output pointInserted: ${test1}")

    pointInserted
  }
```

Below is the controller. As a response I get the model only with the attributes which I pass to the body of the post call and not the attributes generated from the repository.

```
 def insertPointData(): Action[JsValue] =
    Action.async(controllerComponents.parsers.json) { implicit request =>
      {
        request.body
          .validate[Point_LocationModel]
          .fold(
            _ => Future.successful(BadRequest("Cannot parse request body")),
            point => {
              point_LocationRepository.create(point).map { data =>
                Created(Json.toJson(data._2))
              }
            }
          )
      }
    }
```

This is the final response I get from the insert method of controller after the full object is successfully inserted in the db. As shown in the photo the marker_id , id, _creationDate, _updateDate are missing :

```
{
    "step": "string11",
    "backgroundTargetName": "string11",
    "firstPoint": {
        "hitPnt": [],
        "normalX": "string1",
        "normalY": "string1",
        "normalZ": "string1"
    },
    "secondPoint": {
        "hitPnt": [],
        "normalX": "string1",
        "normalY": "string1",
        "normalZ": "string1"
    },
    "x": "1",
    "y": "2",
    "z": "3",
    "rotation": "4",
    "note": "test3",
    "tag": "test3",
    "work_session_id": "TEST"
}
```

How can I get the full object inserted in the database ?

Comment: Please do not share code as image but as text so that it's easier to read, copy or search for

Comment: 1. Naming with `_` is not recommended in Scala, specially in case class. 2. A driver cannot do something the server doesn't do, so first design your query (e.g. using MongoShell) then integrate programmatically